# colon operator sequence in R

Tags: r

Why when I use colon operator to generate a sequence it will give me different results from using (from,to) if starting number is less than 0?
i.e.:

```
seq1 = seq(-1,10)
```

returns

```
-1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

whereas

```
seq = seq(-1:10)
```

returns

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are expecting with `seq(-1:10)`. The `:` operator is a shortcut to `seq` itself. So that's the same as `seq(seq(-1, 10))` which is also the same as

```
x <- -1:10
seq(x)
```

and when you only pass a single parameter to `seq()` and that single parameter has a length greater than 1, it will return a sequence of the same length at that vector starting at one. Basically it behaves like `seq_along` in that case. See the `?seq` help page for more info. See also

```
seq(c("a","b","c"))
#[1] 1 2 3
```